# ggplot monthly date scale on x axis uses days as units

Tags: r, ggplot2

When plotting a bar chart with monthly data, ggplot shortens the distance between February and March, making the chart look inconsistent[image: here is an example]

```
  require(dplyr)
  require(ggplot2)  
  require(lubridate)


## simulating sample data 

set.seed(.1073)
my_df <- data.frame(my_dates = sample(seq(as.Date('2010-01-01'), as.Date('2016-12-31'), 1), 1000, replace = TRUE))


### aggregating + visualizing counts per month 

my_df %>%  
  mutate(my_dates = round_date(my_dates, 'month')) %>%  
  group_by(my_dates) %>%  
  summarise(n_row = n()) %>%  
  ggplot(aes(x = my_dates, y = n_row))+ 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', color = 'black',fill = 'slateblue', alpha = .5)+
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = 'months', date_labels = '%y-%b') +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would keep the dates as dates rather than factors. Yes, factors will keep the bars uniform in size but you'll have to remember to join in any months that are missing so that blank months aren't skipped and factors are easy to get out of order. I would recommend adjusting your aesthetics to reduce the effect that the black outline has on the gap between February and March.

Here are two examples:

- Adjust the outline color to be white. This will reduce the contrast and makes the gap less noticible.
- Set the width to 20 (days).

As an aside, you don't need to summarize the data, you can use `floor_date()` or `round_date()` in an earlier step and go straight into `geom_bar()`.

```
dates <- seq(as.Date("2010-01-01"), as.Date("2016-12-31"), 1)

set.seed(.1073)
my_df <-
  tibble(
    my_dates = sample(dates, 1000, replace = TRUE),
    floor_dates = floor_date(my_dates, "month")
  )

ggplot(my_df, aes(x = floor_dates)) +
  geom_bar(color = "white", fill = "slateblue", alpha = .5)

ggplot(my_df, aes(x = floor_dates)) +
  geom_bar(color = "black", fill = "slateblue", alpha = .5, width = 20)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it to a factor variable to use as the axis, and fix the formatting with a label argument to scale_x_discrete.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)


my_df %>%  
  mutate(my_dates = factor(round_date(my_dates, 'month'))) %>% 
  group_by(my_dates) %>%  
  summarise(n_row = n()) %>%  
  ggplot(aes(x = my_dates, y = n_row))+ 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', color = 'black',fill = 'slateblue', alpha = .5)+
  scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) format(as.Date(x), '%Y-%b'))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1))
```

Edit: Alternate method to account for possibly missing months which should be represented as blank spaces in the plot.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)


to_plot <- 
  my_df %>%  
    mutate(my_dates = round_date(my_dates, 'month'),
           my_dates_ticks = interval(min(my_dates), my_dates) %/% months(1))

to_plot %>% 
  group_by(my_dates_ticks) %>%  
  summarise(n_row = n()) %>%  
  ggplot(aes(x = my_dates_ticks, y = n_row))+ 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', color = 'black',fill = 'slateblue', alpha = .5)+
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = unique(to_plot$my_dates_ticks),
    labels = function(x) format(min(to_plot$my_dates) + months(x), '%y-%b'))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1))
```

Comment: But then there are other distances/gaps, e.g. Juliy to Sep 2010 or Dez 2013 to Feb 2014, right?

Comment: Oh, yeah if you have no observations for a certain month and want to show that as a gap in the plot, this method would require you to %>% right_join with a data frame having all months first.

Comment: Added another method

Answer (score 1):

using some parts from IceCream's answer you can try this. 
Of note, `geom_col` is now recommended to use in this case.

```
my_df %>%  
  mutate(my_dates = factor(round_date(my_dates, 'month'))) %>% 
  group_by(my_dates) %>%  
  summarise(n_row = n()) %>%  
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(my_dates_x = as.numeric(my_dates)) %>% 
  mutate(my_dates_label = paste(month(my_dates,label = T), year(my_dates))) %>% 
  {ggplot(.,aes(x = my_dates_x, y = n_row))+ 
   geom_col(color = 'black',width = 0.8, fill = 'slateblue', alpha = .5) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = .$my_dates_x, labels = .$my_dates_label) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1))}
```

[image]